# Complex filtering with data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to select information by different group in a data.frame (or **data.table**), but didn't find the proper way of doing it. Consider the following example:

```
DF <- data.table(value=c(seq(5,1,-1),c(5,5,3,2,1)),group=rep(c("A","B"),each=5),status=rep(c("D","A","A","A","A"),2))

   value group status
 1:     5     A      D
 2:     4     A      A
 3:     3     A      A
 4:     2     A      A
 5:     1     A      A
 6:     5     B      D
 7:     5     B      A
 8:     3     B      A
 9:     2     B      A
10:     1     B      A
```

I'd like now to get the max value by group when the status is alive ("A"). I have tried this:

```
DF[,.I[value==max(value[status!="D"])],by=group]

       group V1
1:     A  2
2:     B  6
3:     B  7
```

But the 6th row is status "D" (dead) and I'd like to avoid that row. I can't subset the data like this:

```
DF[status!="D",.I[value==max(value[status!="D"])],by=group]
```

as I need to compute different stats by groups, such as (doesn't work):

```
  DF[,list("max"=max(value[status!="D"],na.rm=T),"group"=group[.I[value==max(value[status=="D"],na.rm=T)]]),by=group]]
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can u show the expected output as I am a bit lost

Comment: If we check `DF[status != "D", .I[value == max(value)], by = group]$V1#[1] 2 7` 6 is not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need an index based on 'status' that are not 'D' and 'value' is `max` of 'value' grouped by 'group'

```
i1 <- DF[status != "D", .I[value == max(value)], by = group]$V1
```

Use the index for further summarizing

```
DF[i1, .SD[value == max(value)], group]
```

Comment: Also `DF[DF[status =="A",.I[value==max(value)], by=group]$V1]` using `.I`

Comment: Just to be sure for other readers... we are using a data.table here. Which is *slightly* different from a data.frame

Comment: Generally, subsetting within groups with `i` is risky, since you may lose groups unexpectedly, in this case if there's a group that's never alive / "A".

Comment: @akrun: Thanks for your feedback. As mentioned in the second part of my message, I can't subset the whole data doing `DF[status=="A",.SD[value==max(value)],by=group]`, as I further need to summarize information by _status_, as follow: 
`DF[,list("max"=max(value[status!="D"],na.rm=T),"group"=group[.I[value==max(value[status=="D"],na.rm=T)]]),by=group]]`. Clearer?

Comment: @Ervan Did you meant `i1 <- DF[status != "D", .I[value == max(value)], by = group]$V1;
 DF[i1, .SD[value == max(value)], group]`

Comment: @akrun: Not really, but your suggestion made me realize that I can overcome the problem by creating an index externally and use it here to summarize information by _status_. Would you mind update your initial answer to reflect your last comment? Or shall I post an answer to my own comment?